# How to add calculated column to a pivot table connected to SSAS tabular model?

Tags: excel, pivot, sql-server-2014, dax, ssas-tabular

Or in another words the question is - how to add some calculation in the pivot table based on columns which do not exist in model level.

I've reproduced my problem using **AdventureWorksDW2014** sample database.

Let's say I want to calculate difference between Actual and Budget scenario amounts in the **FactFinance** table for each Organisation and present it in a form of pivot table.

[image: tabular model]

To achieve that I've created a simple model (screen above) and added **SumOfAmount** measure to the **FactFinance** table `SumOfAmount:=SUM([Amount])`

Next, I've opened my model in Excel and created very simple pivot table (shown below)

[image: pivot field ist]
[image: pivot in excel]

So, (the question part) now I want to add an extra column to my pivot table, which should calculate something (for example difference) between columns **Actual** and **Budget**. And I want this new column been a part of the pivot table so I could filter it or\and add new grouping levels without necessity to change something "outside" the pivot table.

---

**TRIED SO FAR**

I tried to add **Calculated Field** but it seems like I can only use "real" columns for calculations. Columns which appeared in a pivot table based on values from COLUMNS quadrant can't be used as sources for calculations.

[image]

---

**FINAL SOLUTION**

I got it finally combined two pivot tables: the old one and the one with `Diff` measure, defined as `Diff:=[Actual Amount]-[Budget Amount]`, where

```
Actual Amount:=Calculate([SumOfAmount];'DimScenario'[ScenarioName] = "Actual")
Budget Amount:=Calculate([SumOfAmount];'DimScenario'[ScenarioName] = "Budget")
```

as @WimV suggested
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculated measure is good:

```
SumOfAmount:=SUM('FactFinance'[Amount])
```

Add the following Calculated measures (if needed mark as hidden):

```
Budget Amount:=Calculate([SumOfAmount],'DimScenario'[Scenariokey] = "Budget")
Actual Amount:=Calculate([SumOfAmount],'DimScenario'[Scenariokey] = "Actual")
```

You can use the new calculations for example in a difference calculations